# Xcode Playground vs. Project -- Type 'ClosedInterval<int>' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'

Tags: xcode, swift, swift-playground

I'm creating a board game in which I assign a tag to each row and column using ranges. I tested a subset of it in the Playground, and it worked as I expected:

```
var board = [ [ 110...112, 120...122], [ 210...212, 220...222] ]

for row in board {
  print("Row: \(row)\n")
  for col in row {
    print(" Col: \(col)\n")
    for tag in col {
      print("    \(tag)\n")
    }
  }
}
```

Printing:

```
Row: [110..<113, 120..<123]
 Col: 110..<113
    110
    111
    112
 Col: 120..<123
    120
    121
    122
Row: [210..<213, 220..<223]
 Col: 210..<213
    210
    211
    212
 Col: 220..<223
    220
    221
    222
```

Pardon the long printout -- just wanted to verify that `col` values are indeed ranges that can be used in a for..in loop. When I try to compile this in my project, I get the error:

```
for tag in col {     <! Type 'ClosedInterval<int>' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'
```

If I change `for tag in col {` to `for tag in 110...112 {` the error goes away,  and I get a confused look on my face and flail away at down casting, cursing that "they are the !$%1@ing same thing!!!", and generally pounding on my keyboard. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The snippet from your question builds and runs as expected in my XCode 6.4 and XCode 7 beta 2.

Comment: I sometimes notice similar weird behaviour too (e.g. something that is syntactically correct would not compile).  Usually cleaning the product and rebuilding the project from scratch helps.

Comment: Thank you Anton. After seeing your comment, I tried again (both Xcode 6.3.2 and 7/Beta 2) and _it worked in both!_  I _did_ restart my machine for other reasons in between. While in my down casting rage, I found that `var board: [[Range<int>]] = [ [ . . .` also helped (but did't make sense from a Swift perspective. In any case, I'm no longer seeing the issue and I appreciate you taking the time to try it on your system.